# Powershell ListView.ItemsSource type error

Tags: wpf, powershell, xaml

I'm struggling with sending variables from one file to another.

Here's function from my main file:

```
Function Set-ManagerWindowForms ($Manager){

$WPFManager.Text = $Manager.DisplayName

$accounts = .\Scripts\Helpers\FindUserAlike.ps1 -FirstName_Param $Manager.GivenName -LastName_Param $Manager.Surname -Domain_Param "domain.com"
$WPFAccountListView.ItemsSource = $accounts
    
}
```

And the helping function I'm calling looks like this:

```
param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)][String]$FirstName_Param,
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)][String]$LastName_Param,
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)][String]$Domain_Param
)

$accounts = Get-ADUser -Filter {GivenName -like $FirstName_Param -and Surname -like $LastName_Param} -Server $Domain_Param

$itemSource = @()

ForEach ($account in ($accounts | Sort-Object SamAccountName)) {

    $itemSource += [PSCustomObject]@{

        samAccountName = $account.SamAccountName
        firstName = $account.GivenName
        lastName = $account.Surname

    }

}

return $itemSource
```

Now - when I try to send $accounts to .ItemsSource I'm getting an error message:

```
Exception setting "ItemsSource": "Cannot convert the "@{samAccountName=id; firstName=name; lastName=surname}" value of type "System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject" to type "System.Collections.IEnumerable"."
+     $WPFAccountListView.ItemsSource = $accounts
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], SetValueInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ExceptionWhenSetting
```

Code is working perfectly fine if I place it in the "main" script.
Can't really understand what's happening, I even tried to set **$accounts** to **IEnumerable** type, but it actually gave me even more errors.

Any advice, tip will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `$WPFAccountListView.ItemsSource = $accounts` -> `$WPFAccountListView.ItemsSource = @($accounts)`, to ensure you always assign an array to `ItemsSource` regardless of whether the script return 0, 1, or more items

Comment: Oh cool, didn't know I could do something like that, but it worked.
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

As I believe Mathias commented, you need to return an array each time. To do this you can wrap your variable to make sure you're always returning an array.

```
Function Set-ManagerWindowForms ($Manager){

    $WPFManager.Text = $Manager.DisplayName

    $accounts = .\Scripts\Helpers\FindUserAlike.ps1 -FirstName_Param $Manager.GivenName -LastName_Param $Manager.Surname -Domain_Param "domain.com"
    $WPFAccountListView.ItemsSource = @($accounts)
    
}
```